# How to make object movable only by the player?

Tags: phaser

I'm trying to let the player of my PhaserJS game (with MatterJS physics) **move a (static?) object** around. That is: the player is allowed to move the object, but otherwise it should be `static` to the world of MatterJS. Here's a minimal scenario reproducing my situation:

```js
class MyScene extends Phaser.Scene {
  create() {
    this.matter.add.rectangle(60, 120, 100, 10).isStatic = true;
    this.matter.add.pointerConstraint({ /* solve it here?! */ });
  }
  
  dropBall() {
    this.matter.add.circle(150, 20, 10);
  }
}

const game = new Phaser.Game({
  banner: false,
  width: 300,
  height: 150,
  physics: {
    default: 'matter',
    matter: { debug: true, setBounds: true },
  },
  scene: [MyScene]
});

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  document.getElementById("start").addEventListener("click", () => {
    game.scene.getScenes(false)[0]?.dropBall();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/phaser/3.55.2/phaser.min.js"></script>
<div>1. Move platform to middle. 2. Then <button id="start">Drop a ball!</button></div>
```

I want the player to *only* be able to move the `static` rectangle around with the mouse. Technically the ball-dropping feature in my example is not needed for the question, but I'd hope it gives some context. Plus it shows that the `pointerConstraint` does *something* because you now *can* move the balls around (which shouldn't be possible).

Comment: In other physics engines, this would usually be implemented as a kinematic body - one that can push other objects but not be pushed itself, outside of code that directly changes its position. Searching for "matter-js kinematic" turns up some [threads on achieving something similar in this library](https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/issues/498).

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to game development and knowing the terminology already helps! Will see if the workarounds in that issue could help me out as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the builtin phaser functions, you just need to create a *phaser-matter-gameboject*, like an image ([link to the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Physics.Matter.Image.html)), and that you configer it to be draggable.

1. create matter-image
2. make image interactive `setInteractive`
3. make image draggable `this.input.setDraggable(...)`
4. in the `drag` Event update the position of the image

**Here a short demo, showcasing this:**
*(based on your codesnippet)*

```js
class MyScene extends Phaser.Scene {
  create() {
    // START - just creating an image for the demo  
    let graphics  = this.make.graphics();
    graphics.fillStyle(0xffffff);
    graphics.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 10);
    graphics.generateTexture('paddle', 100, 10);
    // END - just creating an image for the demo  

    let paddle = this.matter.add.image(60, 120, 'paddle').setStatic(true);
    
    paddle.setInteractive();
    this.input.setDraggable(paddle);

    this.input.on('drag', function (pointer, gameObject, dragX, dragY) {
        paddle.x = dragX;
        paddle.y = dragY;
    });
  }
  
  dropBall() {
    this.matter.add.circle(150, 20, 10);
  }
}

const game = new Phaser.Game({
  banner: false,
  width: 300,
  height: 150,
  physics: {
    default: 'matter',
    matter: { debug: true, setBounds: true },
  },
  scene: [MyScene]
});

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  document.getElementById("start").addEventListener("click", () => {
    game.scene.getScenes(false)[0]?.dropBall();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/phaser/3.55.2/phaser.min.js"></script>
<div>1. Move platform to middle. 2. Then <button id="start">Drop a ball!</button></div>
```

Comment: Woa! So confusing that `.add.rectangle(...)` is _functionally_ different from `.add.image(...)`. Your answer is _excactly_ the effect I was after. Thanks!